# Purpose of WCF Client Endpoint?

Tags: wcf, client, endpoint

I understand the purpose of having WCF endpoint on the service side, but I don't quite understand the purpose of configuring endpoint on the client side. Is this for duplex connection or something?

Regards

James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An endpoint is effectively a tuple of (address, binding, contract).

The client has all these things, just like the server.  (In client side it is address you want to connect to, binding used to talk to the server, contract used for the messages.)

Comment: So when you add a service reference on the client side in visual studio 2008, does it automatically creates the client endpoint configuration?

Comment: Yes (I think you get am app.config file by default with all that info).